# How can I install a package from a code like the code in the picture?

Tags: errors, packages, logicproof

I am trying to use a package for natural deduction, this is fitch.sty.

So, I wrote in Text Maker before "\begin{document}" the following: "\usepackage{fitch}". But the an error arised, this is "File 'fitch.sty' not found". Then I searched for solutions, one of this solutions suggest to install it manually, but I have a problem, for installing it manually I need to have the file, and I don´t have the file, I have something like this:
[image]

So, how can I install something like this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If this is the file `fitch.sty`, you can save this file under exactly this name and move it to your working directory. Then you can use `\usepackage{fitch}` to tell LaTeX to use this file. You don't need to install it, if you only need it for this document.

Comment: It seems that the file can be downloaded from: https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/fitch/